# My mobile menu code flashes the menu first when page loads, then hides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, menu

I've used this script on several sites, and it is getting to the point where I have so many sites with this same bug that I need help resolving this once and for all so I do not keep moving the same bug to new production servers

I had a contractor come up with the following for a WordPress mobile menu. It works great, but unfortunately when page first loads the menu loads over the content, and then hides. I cannot figure out for the life of me what is causing this, or what extra JavaScript command I should add to the code to remove the hide on page load.

Here is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//mobile menu
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#menu_btn').click(function() {
        if(jQuery('#main_menu').is(':visible')) {
            jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () { 
                jQuery("#main_menu").css('display', 'none');
                jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'none');  
            });
        } else {
            jQuery("#main_menu").css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow', function(){
                jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'block'); 
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery('#menu_close').click(function() {
        jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () { 
            jQuery("#main_menu").css('display', 'none'); 
        });
    });

    callOnResize();
});

jQuery(window).resize( function(){
    callOnResize();
});

function callOnResize() {
    var winwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if (winwidth < 760) {
        jQuery( '#main_menu' ).css({ display: 'none' });
        jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow');
    } else if (winwidth >= 760) {
        jQuery( '#main_menu' ).css({ display: 'block' });
    }
}
</script>
```

And it works on any menu that has the following:

```
<ul id="main_menu">
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Any time you spend on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add media rule in your css like following, and then remove callOnResize() from your js.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    #main_menu {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 761px) {
    #main_menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code i am using for the mobile menu must be super buggy, because this solution you propose is not working. when i remove the callOnResize() then the menu shows and is never removed.

Comment: did you add the css rule in your head?

Comment: ok what you propose worked. i added the css to head of the header file and removed the callOnResize(). but it only works when i put the media query in the head of the header file. when i put it in my css file it does not work. thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

Your menu should be hidden and out of sight in the beginning. Do this:

```
 #main_menu{ left: -100%; display: none;}
 #menu_close{ display: none;}
```

Comment: when i added it to here - http://zachis.it/ - the menu still flashes on page load. thoughts?

Comment: Firstly the site you've mentioned was down. Now the site is up but I do not see the implementation of my suggestion. and you unaccepted my answer.

Comment: view-source:http://zachis.it/ - line 145 and 146. i deselected your answer because it is not working on my site.

Comment: Line 145 and 146 are Javascript code which is triggered on resize etc. What I suggested was to add the default style to your CSS so it starts as hidden. The fix goes in style/CSS and not in JavaScript.

Comment: hmm. i just added it to another site i am using this script - chinesebloomington.com - and it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As [Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218154/allen)
   said you have to remove callOnResize() function from javascript like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//mobile menu
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#menu_btn').click(function() {
        if(jQuery('#main_menu').is(':visible')) {
            jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () { 
            jQuery("#main_menu").css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'none');  
        });
    } else {
        jQuery("#main_menu").css('display', 'block');
        jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow', function(){
            jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'block'); 
        });
    }
});


 jQuery('#menu_close').click(function() {
        jQuery('#main_menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () { 
            jQuery("#main_menu").css('display', 'none'); 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And just add css like this for show/hide menu according screen size:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
 #main_menu {
   display: none;
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 761px) {
    #main_menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```